# Not able to open excel file in python using xlrd

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 and the latest xlrd package.

```
import xlrd
xfile = xlrd.open_workbook("random_stuff.xlsx");
```

The above code gives me an error that says :

```
un(shallow)copyable object of type <type 'Element'>
```

and takes me to a file by the name of `cElementTree.py` which contains this :

```
# Wrapper module for _elementtree

from _elementtree import *
```

What is the error i simply don't get it. I am fairly new to python. I started learning about a month ago.
EDIT : 
Using the location method :

```
import xlrd
file_location = "C:\Users\Tanmay\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\random_stuff.xlsx"
xfile = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location , r)
```

gives the following error :

```
[Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\Tanmay\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\PythonApplication1\\PythonApplication1\random_stuff.xlsx'
```

Comment: I also have the excel file in the same directory as the python code and i have also tried the "location" method but it gives me the same error

Comment: Is there anything complex in the spreadsheet? Embedded things, images, charts? Anything apart from plain data? Does it work with other Excel files for you?

Comment: Absolutely not. It has 2 columns one contains letters A-Z , one in each column and the second one contains numbers from 1-26 one in each column

Comment: Can you share that spreadsheet then? Because if it works for anyone else then the problem is somewhere in your setup...

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9bPb9OHEE6uNmlSOFh0RjhHVXc       Link to excel file

Comment: Your first code block works fine for me, python 2.7.6, xlrd 1.0.0. Something must be broken with your python libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the raw string instead

```
file_location = r"C:\Users\Tanmay\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\random_stuff.xlsx"
```

Comment: gives error : un(shallow)copyable object of type <type 'Element'> and leads to the same "cElementTree.py" file